# Running make gives "multiple definition of ... first defined here" error

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, gnu-make

I have following project structure:

```
ProjectX
├── Module1
│   ├── Module2
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── Module2.cpp // has #include "Common.h"
│   │   └── include
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── src
│   │   └── Class1.cpp  // has #include "Common.h"
│   │   └── Class2.cpp // has #include "Common.h"
│   └── include
│       └── Class1.h  // has #include "Class2.h"  ** NOTE **
├── Module3
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── src
│   │   └── Class3.cpp // has #include "Common.h"
│   └── include
├── src
│   └── NewClass.cc // newly added
├── include
│   ├── NewClass.h // newly added
│   └── Common.h // newly added
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

`Commonn.h` contains instances of `NewClass` to be used by all Modules:

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include "NewClass.h"

namespace ProjectX {
    extern NewClass instance1 = NewClass();
    extern NewClass instance2 = NewClass();
    extern NewClass instance2 = NewClass();
}

#endif // GLOBALS_H
```

I have following CMakeFiles contents:

**ProjectX/CMakeFiles.txt**

```
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED 
src/NewClass.cc
include/NewClass.h
include/Common.h
)
```

**ProjectX/Module1/CMakeFiles.txt** and
**ProjectX/Module2/CMakeFiles.txt**

```
set(PROJECTX_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${PROJECTX_DIR}/include/
)
```

**ProjectX/Module3/CMakeFiles.txt**

```
set(PROJECTX_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${PROJECTX_DIR}/include/
)
```

Also note five `#include`s specified in the ASCII hierarchy at the top.

I am getting following errors while running `make`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class1.cpp.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `ProjectX::instance1'; CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class2.cpp.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class1.cpp.o:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `ProjectX::instance2'; CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class2.cpp.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class1.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `ProjectX::instance3'; CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class2.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Module2/libModule2.a(Module2.cpp.o):(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `ProjectX::instance2'; CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class2.cpp.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Module2/libModule2.a(Module2.cpp.o):(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `ProjectX::instance3'; CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class2.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: Module2/libModule2.a(Module2.cpp.o):(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `ProjectX::instance1'; CMakeFiles/Module1.dir/src/Class2.cpp.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Before including `NewClass.cpp`, `NewClass.h`, and `Common.h`, it was all working just fine. I wanted to add functionality that can be used as a kind of utility across all modules of ProjectX. Thats why I did then code and CMakeLists changes as explained above. But it started to give me above errors. How do I fix this? Also is there any better way to do this?

**Update**

I followed suggestions in answer by `0xbachmann` below. Above error is gone. But now started getting following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Module1/libModule1.so: undefined reference to `ProjectX::instance1'
/usr/bin/ld: Module1/libModule1.so: undefined reference to `ProjectX::NewClass::method(double, double)'
/usr/bin/ld: Module3/libModule3.so: undefined reference to `ProjectX::NewClass::method(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >, double)'
/usr/bin/ld: Module3/libModule3.so: undefined reference to `ProjectX::instance3'
/usr/bin/ld: Module1/libModule1.so: undefined reference to `ProjectX::instance2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why are you **defining** the symbols in a header file that is included more than once?  In that situation, just **declare** those symbols in the header file, and **define** them in the Common.cpp source file.

Comment: What is in NewClass.h? Isn't it possible that you defined `instance1`-`instance3` there?

Comment: `extern whatever = value;` is a definition, despite the `extern`, because it contains an initializer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes I did similar changes. But I started getting new set of errors. I have added an update at the bottom of the original question along with how I added `Module1`, `Module2`, `Module3` in `ProjectX/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @BotondHorváth nope, its just the declarations of different methods and some variables `NewClass`. It does not instantiate anything. And definitely no way I am instantiating `NewClass` inside `NewClass` ...

Comment: @Eljay Yes I did similar changes. But I started getting new set of errors. I have added an update at the bottom of the original question along with how I added `Module1`, `Module2`, `Module3` in `ProjectX/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @MsA -- I rolled back your edits, which drastically rewrote the question. You got a succinct and correct answer to your original question. When you applied it you got different errors; you should post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Even though add the `extern` keyword to this line

```
extern NewClass instance = NewClass();
```

this is a definition because you initialize the `instance` with `NewClass()`.
What you should do, is **declare** the instances in the header file and **define** them in a source file:

Common.h:

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include "NewClass.h"

namespace ProjectX {
    extern NewClass instance1;
    extern NewClass instance2;
    extern NewClass instance2;
}

#endif // GLOBALS_H
```

Some source file, maybe Common.cpp:

```
#include "Common.h"
#include "NewClass.h" // not necessarily needed

namespace ProjectX {
    NewClass instance1 = NewClass();
    NewClass instance2 = NewClass();
    NewClass instance2 = NewClass();
}
```

Then add this source file somewhere in your CMake Project either to your library or to one of your modules

Comment: Given declarations in a file named "globals.h", it would of course be most conventional to put corresponding definitions in a file named "globals.cpp" (".cpp" apparently being the project's conventional extension for C++ source files).  But any regular source file will do, so long as exactly one is chosen.

Comment: That error gone, but started to get new error:

`/usr/bin/ld: Module1/libModule1.so: undefined reference to ProjectX::instance1` 
`/usr/bin/ld: Module1/libModule1.so: undefined reference to ProjectX::NewClass::method(double, double)`   
`/usr/bin/ld: Module3/libModule3.so: undefined reference to ProjectX::instance3`   
`/usr/bin/ld: Module1/libModule1.so: undefined reference to ProjectX::instance2`   
`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` Added to the end of original question for better reading.

Comment: if you want to use these instances in every library, then you need to include the source file in the compilation of every library. but then you will not be able to use these libraries together, as all of them have some same symbols defined. libraries should not depend on global symbols defined outside the library

Comment: I just added the new update section at the bottom of the original question. I included source in the compilation of `ProjectX/CMakeLists.txt` as shown in the update and not to every library. Still it is giving me these errors. Is there no way out?

Comment: Also added how I added Module1, Module2, Module3 in ProjectX/CMakeLists.txt in case it helps to figure out if its still possible to fix the mess I did ...

Comment: why do you have the different modules as libraries? A library needs to be compilable as a singular instance. If you don't need the libraries at any other point, consider just making one single library out of all the sources.

Comment: "why do you have the different modules as libraries" - I inherited this codebase from someone. "just make one single library out of all the sources" - how exactly? Do you suggest replacing `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
PUBLIC Module1 ... ` with something else?  cmake noob here  ...

Comment: I guess somewhere you have `add_library(ModuleX STATIC ModuleX.cpp)` you can try to replace it with `add_library(ModuleX OBJECT ModuleX.cpp)` this will not link the modules yet and thus not complain about missing symbols.

Comment: Nope. I searched in vscode for string "`add.*ModuleX`" with regex ON. It lists only `add_subdirectory(ModuleX)` in `ProjectX/CMakeLists.txt` as specified in update I added at the end of original question.

Comment: also no additional `add_library()` ? maybe it's not named `Module...` but somwhere cmake needs to know how to make libraries `libModule1.so` etc

Comment: are the `CMakeLists.txt` provided by you in the directories `Module[1|2|3]` complete or did you cut out some code?

Comment: Yes, there is no additional `add_library()` in `ProjectX/CMakeLists.txt` at least for `Module[1|2|3]`, but it has `add_subdirectory(Module[1|2|3])`. How can we let cmake  know how to make libraries libModule1.so etc? And, no, those CMakeLists for Module[1|2|3] are not complete. There are a lot of stuffs regarding other things not related to this doubt...

Comment: This error `/usr/bin/ld: Module1/libModule1.so: undefined reference to...` tells me that somewhere in the CMakeLists there needs to be a command to build a shared library called Module1. This needs to be changed if you want to use a global object accross all files